# Hadamard product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've encountered a notion of Hadamard product, if $A=[a_{ij}],B=[b_{ij}]$ are $n\times n$ matrices then their Hadamard product is $A\circ B=[a_{ij}\ b_{ij}]$.

My question is what does it represent, as standard matrix multiplication represents composition of linear maps? I didn't find too much about it safe for definition and basic properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.04301) that works with Hadamard product; you don't need to read this paper, but in the first paragraph of the introduction the authors suggest some papers and books that use Hadamard product. You can look at those to see some of the ways it has come up.